# Extension of Folland proposition 3.11

Tags: real-analysis

With proof marked as trivial in Folland, there is:

> 3.11 **Proposition**. If $\mu_1, \dots, \mu_n$ are sigma finite measures on $(X, \mathscr{M})$, there is a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_{j} << \mu$ for all $j$ - namely $\mu = \sum_{ij=1}^{n}\mu_{j}$

Proving this is very easy, just writing out the definition of dominating measures. In my UC notes though, there is a second part - it states that 
$$
d\mu_{1} / d\mu + \dots + d\mu_{n} / d\mu = 1
$$
almost everywhere. This seems less trivial to me - how can I show this? I try writing out all the components in integral form but it is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int\sum_{j}\dfrac{d\mu_{j}}{d\mu}d\mu&=\sum_{j}\int\dfrac{d\mu_{j}}{d\mu}d\mu\\
&=\sum_{j}\mu_{j}\\
&=\mu,
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\mu=\int1d\mu,
\end{align*}
so by Radon-Nikodym uniqueness, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{j}\dfrac{d\mu_{j}}{d\mu}=1$ a.e.

Here some $\sigma$-finite property should be assumed.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. One question - when you say "so by Radon-Nikodym uniqueness", you just mean that each $d\mu_j / d\mu$ is an equivalence class of functions, so their sum determines an equivalence class as well?

Comment: Yes, we pick any of the representatives.

Answer (score 0):

By the Radon-Nikodym theorem you have there exist integrable functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu_j = f_j\, \mu$ for every $j=1,\ldots,n$. (And $f_j =: d\mu_j / d\mu$ by definition.)

Hence
$$
\mu = \sum_j \mu_j = \left(\sum_j f_j\right)\mu,
$$
so that $\sum_j f_j = 1$ $\mu$-a.e. on $X$.